# Error calling external file in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In `parser.lua` I have a function:

```
local function parsefile()
...
end
```

In `main.lua` I have the following:

```
local parser = require "parser"
parser.parsefile()
```

Both `main.lua` and `parser.lua` are in the same directory.  When I run `main.lua` I get the following error:

> attempt to index local 'parser' (a boolean value)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the best info of scope in Lua watch this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b12YEOIry60

Answer (score 0):

Add the following statement in your `parser.lua`

```
return _G
```

or, alternatively, edit the `parser.lua` to something like:

```
local tParseFunctions = {}
function tParseFunctions.parsefile()
    -- ...
end
function tParseFunctions.anotherFunction()
    -- body
end
return tParseFunctions
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant reach local functions of a module from other modules. Just remove "local" from parser.lua file

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would do it this way:

```
-- parser.lua
local M = {}
function M.parseFile()
  ...
end

return M
```

In main.lua:

```
local parser = require("parser")
parser.parseFile()
```